# Fetching MYSQL records in PHP HTML rendring

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MYSQL table with 400000 records and I query all of them till no problem but when I want loop this records, it takes about 1 or 2 minutes for rendering `<li>` and my question is what is the best way for doing this or rending faster?

My code:

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT series AS ticket_no
          FROM customer
          WHERE status = 0
          order by id
          LIMIT 400000'
          );

<ul class="lottery slot">
    <?php 
     while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            ?>
            <li><span><?=$row['ticket_no']?></span></li>

    <?php  } ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: had you tried adding the paging?

Comment: no need for paging I need long list

Comment: **Stop** using deprecated `mysql_*`API. Use `mysqli_*`or `PDO` with prepared statments

Comment: i think no problem with mysql or mysqli the problem is after that

Comment: Can I suggest trying to generate the entire list as a string using concatenation, and then echo the entire thing, rather than printing out multiple times

Comment: Either add pagination or implement lazy loading up to a  maximum. It looks like there are just too many html elements for the browser to sanely load. But thta is just guessing because you haven't told is what in specific makes it slow.

Comment: TL;DR profile your code

Comment: Doesn't sound like a backend issue, it's more frontend. Do pagination with AJAX and you solve the problem. Of course the browser is struggling with loading 400,000 `<li>` in a single page.

Comment: You need to <?php echo $row['ticket_no'] ?> You missed "echo".

Comment: Can I ask why my answer has been downvoted? Does anyone explicitly know whether this would or would not have an effect on the execution time? As my comment describing the same thing has been upvoted, and because I had the exact same issue with a JavaScript function and this was this solution..